# Elasticsearch/Lucene null handling in doc values

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm planning to use Elasticsearch mostly for data analytics. I have large document with many, moslty numeric (up to 4 bytes) attributes. Most fields in my document only have about 30% of values in them. If I understand correctly I can take advantage of Doc Values feature which is similar to columnar data layout found in some databases. I was wondering how Elasticsearch/Lucene will store this data. Is there any compressions used (e.g. run length) or it is dense data layout where nulls will take the same space on storage as the values?

Comment: will [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html) help?

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of ElasticSearch is not to add the field at all in case of `NULL` values. You can force map the field using `null_value` but for types where `NULL` is supported. For Example: `long` field cannot be mapped with string `null_value`.

So to address the question, ElasticSearch will not allocate default space for fields missing in the document. But you may run into `MissingFieldException` in case you query on some field which never had a value. To avoid this, map your fields explicitly before indexing. If you map explicitly make sure to set the `null_value` property of the field to outside the range of your data input.

Comment: Yes, my intention was to map all the fields I want to filter by. This raises a question though. Will it really set the missing value to 0? I mean, 0 is a valid value and should not be used as replacement for null.

Comment: Sorry, the sentence I wrote interpreted the wrong message. Just edited my answer. ES will not set the default value to 0 for missing fields. It will not set the value at all and you may end up in `MissingFieldException` even if you map explicitly. On the safer side, you can set the value of the `null_value` field to some value outside your input range (like long.MIN_VALUE or int.MIN_VALUE)